# Adding a Qt project to Visual Studio solution with custom build configurations is failing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5

I have a Qt project that was created on windows using visual studio and qt extension. Under the solution there are 5 project and the solution is configured to have custom build configurations like customdebug and customrelease along with debug and release modes.

I would like add to this solution another qt project developed using qt creator. I have used the qt extension on vs to generate a vcxproj and filters files from the pro file.
On trying to add the project to the solution using the generated vcxproj its failing to add with a popup that the project I'm trying to doesn't have any info of the custom build configurations.

How can I update my .pro file to support the custom configurations?

I must add the project by generating vcxproj and filters files from pro file. can't skip this. hence I need a way to update my pro file to support new configurations.